# How to tailor mySQL commands to MariaDB?

Tags: mysql, mariadb

mySQL. MariaDB Server version

I want to run the following command in mySQL, but there is an error in my syntax that phpMyAdmin console states is related to MariaDB server version.

```
Alter table page modify column page_title convert to character set latin1_general_ci
```

How to tailor a mySQL script to MariaDB?

Comment: Why don't you show us the error itself?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The syntax is indeed incorrect, it is not specific to MariaDB, you would have an error with MySQL as well.

You are mixing up different operations. Either you want to change the whole table (all character columns), and then it is

```
ALTER TABLE page CONVERT TO CHARACTER SET <character set>
```

or you want to change the column, and then it is

```
ALTER TABLE page MODIFY COLUMN page_title <column type> CHARACTER SET <character set>
```

Please read the documentation carefully to make sure the command that you choose does what you want, it is not always obvious.

Also, `latin1_general_ci` is not a character set, so you will have another error when you fix the syntax one.

Comment: ALTER TABLE page MODIFY COLUMN page_title varchar(25) COLLATE latin1_general_ci      did the trick! Thankx a a million!!!